# hit enter to click button VC#

Tags: c#

I'm working on a WinForm App in C#, and there is only one button on app's screen, app's need is when user hit to enter, button should work as clicked to it. How can this be possible?

Answer (score 8):

Your form has an "AcceptButton" property.

Set it to the button in question and it will behave as you describe.

Please see the documentation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Set the form's `AcceptButton` property to the button you want executed when the user hits Enter.

Answer (score 2):

goto form properies Set `AcceptButton` to your button ID

Answer (score 2):

Use This :

```
this.AcceptButton = button1 // Say you want to set Enter to button1
```

[Know More about `AcceptButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[Form.AcceptButton Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton.aspx)

Gets or sets the button on the form that is clicked when the user presses the ENTER key.

```
// Set the accept button of the form to button1.
   form1.AcceptButton = button1;// button1 is your required button
```

Additional information

For cencel you can use

```
form1.CancelButton = MyCancelButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in client side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function searchKeyPress(sender, eventArgs) {
                var c = eventArgs.get_keyCode();
                if (c == 13) {
                    var btnQiuckSearch = document.getElementById('<%=RbSearch.ClientID%>');
                    btnQiuckSearch.click();
                }
            }
 </script>
```